# Firebase Tensorflow Lite Classification Model Not Giving Correct Output in Swift App

Tags: python, swift, firebase, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

So I am trying to create an app that can classify hand written numbers (not from an MNIST data set, I created my own data set of jpeg images) with a Tensorflow CNN model saved as a .tflite file and stored in Firebase. The model works correctly and produced a validation accuracy of 0.78 when training. I then saved the model and its weights to a .pb file and converted that to a .tflite file. Once I had the .tflite file, I was able to upload it to Firebase Custom MLKit. I then created an iOS app that takes pictures, it then connects to Firebase and downloads the model and creates an interpreter that outputs probabilities. It all supposedly works properly and throws no errors or warnings, but when the output comes back from the interpreter, it is not accurate compared to the original model. When I test it with various data, the output barely changes (the probabilities stay the same, as if I was testing it with the same input). I posted the basic code for both the Swift app and the TensorFlow 2.0 CNN to GitHub [here](https://github.com/IkeHunter/Number-Classifier-Code). What could possibly be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to download your [model file](https://github.com/IkeHunter/Number-Classifier-Code/blob/master/Number_Guesser_CNN/converted_model.tflite) and visualize it using [Netron](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) but it is not a tflite file.

I think you may have had an error during conversion or uploaded an incorrect file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid adding comments in answers section